# jQuery click filter lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists

apologies but i'm fairly new to js. Basically i have the main navigation at the top (#filter), then i have 3 further lists (`#one`, `#two` and `#three`).

What i want to do is when clicked on All it shows all of the list items from `#one`, `#two` and `#three`. Then when clicked on `One` it only shows the list items from `#one`, `Two` from `#two` and `Three` from `#three`.

Here's the mark-up to help.

```
<ul id="filter">
  <li class="current">
    <a href="#">All</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">One</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Two</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Three</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul id="one">
  <li>
    <a href="#">1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">1</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul id="two">
  <li>
    <a href="#">2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">2</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul id="three">
  <li>
    <a href="#">3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $('#filter a').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var clicked = $.trim( $(this).text().toLowerCase() );
        if ( clicked == 'all' ) {
            $('#one, #two, #three').show();
        }else{
            $('#one, #two, #three').hide();
            $('#' + clicked).show();
        }

        $(this).closest('li')
               .addClass('current')
               .siblings()
               .removeClass('current');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm. I had been using else if statements for each of the lists with no joy, but this great!

Comment: How would i go about changing the current class on the #filter list so it moves on to the clicked list item?